# Linux Mint - Windows 8.1 Boot problem

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot

After a clean Windows 8.1 installation I tried to install Linux Mint for dualbooting using a burned DVD. My windows partitions are /dev/sd1 and /dev/sd2. I tried both using the default "install alongside with Windows 8.1" option and (after another clean installation) manually creating the root, home and swap partitions. The problem is that while initially both OSes seem to boot normally, windows sometimes fails to boot, showing random colored lines instead. This doesn't happen if only Windows is installed in my laptop and at this point I am pretty much lost. Any help is much appreciated!